# Passing GPS Co-ordinates to another Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, coordinates

I have an application that displays GPS coordinates in the form of a toast, but what I am trying to achieve is to save these co-ordinates, and display them in the next activity. The problem is.. I cant! I have been working on this for the past 4 days and am at a loss as to how to do so. If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it. Heres a look at the code:

```
public class GPSActivity extends Activity{

double longitude    = 0;
double latitude     = 0;

String s1 = "latitude";
String s2 = "longitude";

public  Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

intent = new Intent(this, Display.class);

/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
LocationManager myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocationListener);} // end activity


/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

       longitude = loc.getLatitude();
       latitude =  loc.getLongitude();

       String text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();



       Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       Bundle extras = new Bundle();

       extras.putDouble("long", longitude);
       extras.putDouble("lat", latitude);

       intent.putExtras(extras);

       startActivity(intent); }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
}

}} // End GPS activity
```

Comment: do you get an error? if yes paste the log. how are you reading the lat & lon values in the other activity?

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't"? What is failing? Or how?

Comment: Sorry, to elaborate, the next activity is NEVER called, if I call startActivity(intent) in the onLocationChanged method. If I try calling the intent in the Activity I get a nullpointerexception.

Comment: It is not related to passing extras. It is related to activity invocation. I am deleting my answer which is not related to this exception.

Comment: Do you have your next activity declared in your manifest? Edit: Also, trying changing "intent = new Intent(this, .." to "intent = new Intent(GPSActivity.this, ..."

Comment: Hi, Yes the manifest file is correct. It is a problem when the activity is calling. I have tried your suggestion and still nothing..

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Try moving "intent = new Intent(this, Display.class);" into your onLocationChanged method. I'm thinking your problem has something to do with trying to start the next activity from your MyLocationListener subclass.

Comment: Ah, I had tried this and a Nullpointerexception is thrown on the Display class as it is unable to display component info.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't store an Intent as a member variable. Create it where you want to start it.

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putDouble("long", longitude);
extras.putDouble("lat", latitude);

Intent newIntent = new Intent(GPSActivity.this, Display.class);
newIntent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Also define your Display activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest . . . >
    . . .
    <application . . .>
        <activity android:name=".Display"
                  . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have tried declared my Intent in the method I wished to start it on two occasions: in the Activity, and in the onLocationChanged class, with the intent in the Activity throwing a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make a class like this

```
String lon; //variable Lon to pass to another activity
String lat; //variable Lat to pass to another activity
public void ALoc(double lon, double lat){
    this.lon = String.valueOf(lon);
    this.lat = String.valueOf(lat);
}
```

Then you put this on your onLocationChanged() or what to pass the recent coordinate into String Lon and Lat that declare above.

```
Location lokasiku = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//...
//blabla code
//...
ALoc(lokasiku.getLongitude(), lokasiku.getLatitude());
```

And in the button to go to the next activity who consume this parameter, you should do this pass the parameter via intent on onClick() or what. Assume, you have a GoButton on layout with id: button_Go.

```
    GoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Go);
    GoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("lon", lon);
            intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
            RecentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And now, on the NextActivity, you should get the data that We pass as describe above, looks like this, put it on onCreate().

```
    String lon = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lon");
    String lat = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat");
```

Hope this will help, at least it's already work on me. :D